# How to build a solution from the command line with VS2012 Express?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, command-line

How to build a VC++ solution from the command line with Visual C++ 2012 Express ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a "Developer Command Prompt for VS2012", located in the "Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 --> Visual Studio Tools" in "All Programs".

Type `msbuild /help` to have documentation.

Example: 
`cd` to your solution folder.
type `MSBuild MyApp.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=Win32`

Comment: Thanks for your help, now how to integrate this into another script ?

Comment: Your other script must call the VsDevCmd.bat command file (or vsvars32.bat) located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools in order to setup the environment.