# Build VC++ app using command prompt

Tags: visual-c++

I have an application that successfully builds at the command prompt but I cannot figure out how to do it at the command prompt.  These are my IDE properties for the app:

**Configuration Properties**

```
Include Directories: (nothing modified here)

Library Directories: (nothing modified here)
```

**C++ General**

```
Additional Include Directories: d:\GraphicsMagick\VisualMagick\lib;d:\GraphicsMagick\Magick++\lib;d:\GraphicsMagick;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
```

**Linker**

```
Additional Library Directories: d:\GraphicsMagick\VisualMagick\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)

Input: CORE_RL_magick_.lib;CORE_RL_Magick++_.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)
```

If someone can post an example of how my command is supposed to look like, I would really appreciate that.  Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build a solution from the command line with VS2012 Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065446/how-to-build-a-solution-from-the-command-line-with-vs2012-express)

Comment: Just look at how the IDE does it.  The debug\project.tlog directory has the build command lines.  Typically cl.command.1.tlog for the compiler and link.command.1.tlog for the linker.  Repro them exactly and you'll get the exact same build.  Or simply run msbuild.exe

Comment: @HansPassant that did work, thank you.  The IDE generated command lines to compile and link are absolutely huge!  I did remove a bunch of unneeded flags and libs.